# Doctrine OrderBy on ManyToMany association not working on Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

In this API-Platform API, I am trying to order a relation following [this Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/tutorials/ordered-associations.html).

It returns the error  `"Warning: Undefined array key \"entite\"",` but the field does exist on the target entity.

So here's the code:

src/Entity/Utilisateur

```
    #[
    ORM\JoinTable(name: 'attribut_heritage'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'UtilisateurId', referencedColumnName: 'IdUtilisateur', columnDefinition: "CHAR(14) NOT NULL"),
    ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'AttributId', referencedColumnName: 'IdAttribut', columnDefinition: "CHAR(14) NOT NULL"),
    ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Emr::class),
    ORM\OrderBy(['entite' => 'ASC']),
    Groups(['utilisateur:get'])
]
private Collection $emrHeritage;
```

On src/Entity/Emr

```
    #[
    ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'emrs'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(
        name: 'AttributEntiteId', 
        referencedColumnName: 'IdAttributEntite', 
        nullable: false
    ),
    Groups(['emr:get', 'utilisateur:get'])
]
private ?Entite $entite = null;
```

So, as you can see, `entite` is also an entity.
Actually the objective here is to order the `emrHeritage` collection by a field on the `entite` entity, like so:

```
ORM\OrderBy(['entite.code' => 'ASC']),
```

But it cannot even find the first level relation.

Comment: Have you checked that your schema is valid ? You can run `doctrine:schema:validate` and `doctrine:mapping:info` to check