# API-Platform Doctrine extension unable to add order by many to many association field

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I am attempting to order a collection from a many to many association but not quite getting there.

I am getting the error:

`'emrHeritage ': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

It starts with the following:

src/Entity/Utilisateur

```
    #[
    ORM\JoinTable(name: 'attribut_heritage'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'UtilisateurId', referencedColumnName: 'IdUtilisateur', columnDefinition: "CHAR(14) NOT NULL"),
    ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'AttributId', referencedColumnName: 'IdAttribut', columnDefinition: "CHAR(14) NOT NULL"),
    ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Emr::class),
    Groups(['utilisateur:get'])
]
private Collection $emrHeritage;
```

On the Emr entity the following relations are my target for ordering:

```
    #[
    ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'emrs'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(
        name: 'AttributEntiteId', 
        referencedColumnName: 'IdAttributEntite', 
        nullable: false
    ),
    Groups(['emr:get', 'utilisateur:get'])
]
private ?Entite $entite = null;

#[
    ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'emrs'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(
        name: 'AttributMetierId',
        referencedColumnName: 'IdAttributMetier',
        nullable: false
    ),
    Groups(['emr:get', 'utilisateur:get'])
]
private ?Metier $metier = null;

#[
    ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'emrs'),
    ORM\JoinColumn(
        name: 'AttributRoleId',
        referencedColumnName: 'IdAttributRole',
        nullable: false
    ),
    Groups(['emr:get', 'utilisateur:get'])
]
private ?Role $role = null;
```

Finally, on either the Entite, Metier or Role entities, I need to order by the code field below:

```
    #[
    ORM\Column(name: 'Code', length: 128),
    Groups(['entite:get', 'emr:get', 'utilisateur:get']),
    ApiProperty(
        identifier: true,
        openapiContext: [
            'description' => "Code de l'entité",
            'type' => 'string',
            'example' => 'EXAMPLE'
        ]
    )
]
private ?string $code = null;
```

Then on src/Doctrine/EmrHeritageOrder Extension

```
final class EmrHeritageOrderExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface

    private function orderBy(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
{
    if (Utilisateur::class !== $resourceClass) return;
    $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    // $queryBuilder->addOrderby(sprintf('%s.actif = :isActive', $rootAlias));
    $queryBuilder->orderBy(sprintf('%s.emrHeritage.entite.code', $rootAlias), "ASC");
    // $queryBuilder->setParameter('isActive', self::IS_ACTIVE);
    dump($queryBuilder->getQuery());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your schema is valid ? You can run `doctrine:schema:validate` and `doctrine:mapping:info` to check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine OrderBy on ManyToMany association not working on Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227440/doctrine-orderby-on-manytomany-association-not-working-on-symfony)